# Input maxlength does not work on Android -Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I have an input field and also i need to stop the user from typing more than the allowed character.

```
<input type="text" name="callsign" maxlength="7" >
```

It is working in browser.But not working on android devices?

Comment: I have encountered similar issue with some android browsers.. better to use fallback for `maxlength`

Comment: @Muhsin try using **ng-maxlength="7"**

Comment: @MohanGopi:We can enter characters more than 7

Comment: @Mushin so you need the lenth of the input should be exactly 7 am i right

Comment: No.I need to stop the user from typing more than the allowed character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for all your answers.Your answers didn't me a give a proper solution.Then i have created a directive for that.

**directive.js**

```
myApp.directive('limitChar', function() {
    'use strict';
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            limit: '=limit',
            ngModel: '=ngModel'
        },
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.$watch('ngModel', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                    var length = newValue.toString().length;
                    if (length > scope.limit) {
                        scope.ngModel = oldValue;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
})
```

**html**

```
<input type="text" limit-char limit="7" >
```

Comment: It doesn't work on Android. Try : make to input with a maxLength. Type on the first one. Near the maxLength, type chars without space. You should be able to type more than maxLength. Then, click on the next input. Text on first one is still here.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that maxlength doesn't work on some version of Android. 
you can try to handle the maxlength in your controller.

```
$scope.validateMaxLength = function(input){
  var inputLen = input.length;
  if (inputLen > 7) return false;
  return true;
}
```

and you can call the function in your template/view

```
<input type="text" ng-model="inputModel" ng-keyup="validateMaxLength(inputModel)"
```

Comment: I have 50 input fields,So i need to add 50 functions. It will affect the performance of app.

Comment: @RayonDabre yeah, sorry wrongly put `this` there. but, actually, this also working there.

Comment: @Muhsin you can define the length as your params. `function(input, maxLength)`

Answer (score 2):

Below is the code snippet for Ionic2 with angular

```
import { Directive, EventEmitter, HostListener, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from "ionic-angular";

@Directive({
    selector: '[cMaxLength]'
})
export class MaxLengthDirective {

  @Input('cMaxLength') cMaxLength:any;
  @Output() ngModelChange:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(public platform: Platform) {
  }

  //keypress event doesn't work in ionic android. keydown event will work but the value doesn't effect until this event has finished. hence using keyup event. 
  @HostListener('keyup',['$event']) onKeyup(event) {
    const element = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    const limit = this.cMaxLength;
    if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      const value = element.value.substr(0, limit);
      if (value.length <= limit) {
        element.value = value;
      } else {
        element.value = value.substr(0, limit-1);
      }
      this.ngModelChange.emit(element.value);
    }
  }

  @HostListener('focus',['$event']) onFocus(event) {
    const element = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    if (!this.platform.is('android')) {
      element.setAttribute('maxlength', this.cMaxLength)
    }
  }
}
```

Reference:
http://jagadeeshmanne.blogspot.com/2017/08/ionic-2-angular-maxlength-issue-in.html

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newStylePage.title" (input)="maxlength()" name="styleTitle" id="title" >

maxlength(){
if(newStylePage.title>7) {
    newStylePage.title = newStylePage.title.substring(0,7);
}
}
```

Comment: in the if condition need to check .length so it will be if(newStylePage.title.length > 7)

Answer (score 0):

Try This define the variable in the controller $scope object and use it in HTML

**Controller**

```
myApp.controller('contactCntrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.max = 7;
}]);
```

**Html**

```
<input type="email" id="cont-sum-1" maxlength={{max}}/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @Muhsin. Updated to match with `maxlength`

```
.directive('ionMaxlength', function() {
    'use strict';
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=ngModel'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            scope.$watch('ngModel', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                    var length = newValue.toString().length;
                    if (length > attr.ionMaxlength) {
                        scope.ngModel = oldValue.substr(0, attr.ionMaxlength);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Example

```
<input type="text" ng-model="login.email" ion-maxlength="100">
```