# How to set maxlength for Ionic 1 input type?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

The maxlength HTML5 attribute is not working properly on mobile for text input fields. If the number keypad is enabled it works, but it doesn't work when using text keypad.

Code:

```
<ion-content class="p-l-10 p-r-10 had-header form_page">
<form ng-submit="vm.addAdvance()">
  <div class="list">
    <label class="item item-input InputFormFull">
      <span class="input-label">{{'note_message' | translate}}</span>
       <input type="text" placeholder="{{'notes_message' | translate}}" 
        ng-model="vm.advance.description" id="field2" ng-change="vm.fillStarted()" size="5" maxlength="5" required>
    </label>
    <button class="button trans-but m-t-10" type="submit">{{'save_message' | translate}}</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: can you put your code in a plunker to reproduce this?

Comment: But it works well in browser then what is the issue

Comment: @tanmay browser side its working  but mobile side doesnot work

Comment: @tanmay what is the cause for not working in mobile keypad

Comment: @Ragu I'm sorry, that's what I am saying, we can't possibly know what's going on without getting to see it in action, which won't be possible since it works well in browser

Comment: I think he says that the text length is not working in mobile keypad and he want's to know why it causes the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input maxlength does not work on Android -Ionic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36638071/input-maxlength-does-not-work-on-android-ionic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate: [Input maxlength does not work on Android -Ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36638071/input-maxlength-does-not-work-on-android-ionic)

**Try creating your own directive:**

```
    myApp.directive('limitChar', function() {
    'use strict';
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            limit: '=limit',
            ngModel: '=ngModel'
        },
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.$watch('ngModel', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                    var length = newValue.toString().length;
                    if (length > scope.limit) {
                        scope.ngModel = oldValue;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
})
```

**Html:**

```
<input type="text" limit-char limit="5">
```