# Words are exceeding the limit in text area on Android app (Cordova)

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

Hi I am using this code to take  input in textarea and want to restrict user to not add more then 1000 words. It works fine on Node.js application but when I used this code on my Android application (I am using cordova to make a andriod app). Then same code letting user to enter more then 1000 words. Can anyone guide where error could be As I am on beginner level of it.

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<textarea class="form-control file-box" rows="6"
placeholder="write it here" ng-model="formData.message" required=""
maxlength="1000" name="complaintMessage" ng-keyup="check_complaint_length()"></textarea>
<span style="float: right; color: yellowgreen;">{{1000-formData.message.length}} characters left</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried the directive solution, proposed here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36638071/input-maxlength-does-not-work-on-android-ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36638071/input-maxlength-does-not-work-on-android-ionic)

Comment: @Cosmin  He didnt give a clear answer I think ?

Comment: are you using Ionic? If yes which version?

Comment: @Cosmin yes  2.0.0

Comment: ng-maxlenght might cause problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Ionic v2 then you should have something like:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[max-limit]',
  host: {
    '(keypress)': '_onKeypress($event)',
  }
})
export class MaxLimitDirective {
  @Input('max-limit') maxLimit; 
  _onKeypress(e) {
     const limit = +this.maxLimit;
     if (e.target.value.length === limit) e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Register this in **ngModule** like:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, MaxLimitDirective ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then:

```
<textarea class="form-control file-box" rows="6"
placeholder="write it here" ng-model="formData.message" required=""
maxlength="1000" name="complaintMessage" max-limit="1000" ng-keyup="check_complaint_length()"></textarea>
<span style="float: right; color: yellowgreen;">{{1000-formData.message.length}} characters left</span>
</div>
```