# Restrict User on input field using Javascript in Android

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, angular2-forms

I try to restrict user from typing in input field in android
when user get android keypad below all solution didn't worked

#### Tried Solutions:

1. Preventdefault
2. MaxLength
3. [Input maxlength does not work on Android -Ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36638071/input-maxlength-does-not-work-on-android-ionic?answertab=active#tab-top)

Any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way to disable an input field in HTML is using the disabled attribute:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp

An example would be:

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" disabled="disabled"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PreventDefault has nothing to do with disabling an input as far as I understand. MaxLength would in theory work, but it is hacky and not as apparent what the goal of the code is.

Disabled can be bound to however you like, just like any other attribute in Angular. So you could do something like `[disabled]="shouldDisable()"` where `shouldDisable()` is a method on the component that returns a truthy or falsy value.

Also, ion-input may have some special behavior, but I'm not aware of it. You can read further here: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-disable-ion-input/42522